# Horizontal menu scrollbar in HTML/CSS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

**I just want to move the menu horizontally and not vertically;(mobile view)**.
The problem is that when the user touches on the parent menu so the child menu goes behind the items list as shown in the image.

[image: here is the folowing image]

Is there any Jquery way to make the dropdown move forward? This is the following code which I am using:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.exfd-filter {
    overflow-x: auto !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
```

Comment: This can easily be done with the CSS [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property

Comment: z-indez propety is also not working in this plugin, that's the reason I am stuck

Comment: Please provide enough information and code for us to be able to replicate the problem, preferably as a [mcve]. "z-indez propety is also not working in this plugin" - What plug in?